# Custom TabHost- problem Handling childs added in XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I have built a custom component, which extends `TabHost` and adds the needed `TabwWidget` and `FrameLayout` with the required `Ids` by default.

This works just fine, but I would like to handle the childs defined in an xml file.

```
<my.custom.TabHost>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"></LinearLayout>          
</my.custom.TabHost>
```

If its defined like this I would like to automatically call a method which makes a `TabSpec` from the `View` and adds it to the `TabHost`.

But I dont know when the children are added to the `View`, so I dont know where to check if I should add the `Views` normally, or make a `TabSpec` out of it.

Is there a way to achieve this?

After Constructor just the 2 default Children(`TabWidget`, `FrameLayout`) are added, `childcount is 2`.

After onlayout, `childCount is 3`. But which methoid is called between?

I checked `addVIewInLayout`, but still no effect.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.  It was so simple, I didn't check this first ;-)

Just override all methods of `addview`, and check in them if it is one of the Two required `Views` for `TabHost`, and then call `super.addView()`, otherwise create the `TabSpec` from the `View` and add it via `addTab()`.